# Clone SXA Search result

Tags: sxa, content-search

I am using SXA 1.6 Clone Feature to clone SXA Search result render to new one with  custom .cshtml file so I can change the markup of the container instant of `<ul> <li>` to `<div>`tags , however I have noticed if I change

```
<div @Html.Sxa().Component(Model.Rendering.RenderingCssClass ?? "search-results", Model.Attributes) data-class-variant="@variantClass" data-properties='@Model.JsonDataProperties'>
```

to

```
<div @Html.Sxa().Component(Model.Rendering.RenderingCssClass ?? "FeaturedNews-search-results", Model.Attributes) data-class-variant="@variantClass" data-properties='@Model.JsonDataProperties'>`
```

With the changes done in "**RenderingCssClass**" there is no search result and when I try to change the class with the below code its not reflecting on the rendered results

```
<ul class="search-result-list">

        <li>
            @foreach (BaseVariantField variantField in Model.VariantFields)
            {
                @Html.RenderingVariants().RenderVariant(variantField, Model.PageItem, false)
            }
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: First of all you need to check if you are getting any results at all. Please inspect the JSON which is returned from the server if there are any results. You can also try with standard Search Results. Put it on the page and check if your search is configured properly.

Comment: Yes iam getting result when the RenderingCssClass is "search-results"

Comment: I'll check that for you tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I promised I've checked this for you. So the first place to looks in case of search renderings is the JavaScript file (most of the search renderings works on the fron-end). Take a look at `component-search-results.js`:

[image]

This is just a part of code but you can already see that it requires the `search-results` css class. So what you should do is:

```
<div @Html.Sxa().Component(Model.Rendering.RenderingCssClass ?? "search-results FeaturedNews-search-results", Model.Attributes) data-class-variant="@variantClass" data-properties='@Model.JsonDataProperties'>`
```

What is more, take a look at the beginning of `component-search-results.js`. The template to build search results unsorted list (`<ul><li>`) is defined at the beginning of that file.

Comment: Thank you so much fro your help , i tried to look for this js inside my theme but its look like its retrieved from BaseTheme  , to add my own html markup shall i duplicate the file ?

Comment: do you have any recommendation for extensions